# How do i sum the 2 columns per row using listView c#

Tags: c#, listview

I'm using c# windows form. how do i sum the 2 Colums per row using listView? and divide it into 2? and the total will show in 3rd column?

this is my example code, my code sum all of the sub items and i cant view it on the 3rd column.

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListViewItem lstItem in listView1.Items)
    {            
        gtotal = int.Parse(lstItem.SubItems[2].Text);
        total += int.Parse(lstItem.SubItems[3].Text);
        totals = int.Parse(lstItem.SubItems[4].Text);            
    }
}
```

[image: This is my listView Table]

Comment: FWIW, it is much easier to use a DataGridView for this because it is an actual grid control and can store numbers

Comment: I agree with @Plutonix. Is there a specific reason why you're using a `ListView`? A `DataGridView` would be much easier to work with for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    foreach (ListViewItem lstItem in listView1.Items)
    {            
        gtotal = int.Parse(lstItem.SubItems[2].Text); //Detail Column
        total = int.Parse(lstItem.SubItems[3].Text);  //Detail2 Column
        lstItem.SubItems[4].Text = gtotal + total // Sum of 2 Column of details           
    } 
 }
```